# TextClassification/ Extraction from image How to get single text frame and string Using Core ML from a Image

Tags: ios, swift, text-classification, coreml, vision

Need to mark the rec boxes around string and then to get that string after tapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import Vision


class ViewController: UIViewController, ImageGet {

//MARK: OUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIButton!

//MARK: VARIABLES
var objU = UtilityClass()
var image:UIImage?
var str:String?
var uiButton : UIButton?
var arrayString = [String]()
var imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView()

//MARK: DELEGATE FUNCTION

func img(image: UIImage) {
    self.image = image
    imageView.image = image
    setUp()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//MARK: SETUPUI
func setUp() {
    let realImg =  resizeImage(image: (imageView.image!) , targetSize:CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height) )
    self.image = realImg
    self.imageView .image = self.image
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: realImg.size.width, height: realImg.size.height)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    guard let cgimg = realImg.cgImage else {return}
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgimg)
    let req = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
    req.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    do {
        try requestHandler.perform([req])
    } catch {
        print("Unable to perform the request: \(error)")
    }
}

//MARK: SELECT THE IMAGE
@IBAction func selectButtontapped(_ sender: Any) {
    objU.delegate = self
    objU.obj = self
    objU.ImageGet()
}

  func recognizeTextHandler(request : VNRequest , error:Error?) {
    guard let observation = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation], error == nil else {
        return
    }
    _ = observation.compactMap({
        $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string
    }).joined(separator: "/n")
    
    for subView in imageView.subviews {
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    let boundingRect :[CGRect]  = observation.compactMap{
        observation in
        guard let candidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else {return .zero}
        //find the bounding box observation
        let stringRange = candidate.string.startIndex..<candidate.string.endIndex
        let boxObservation = try? candidate.boundingBox(for: stringRange)
        let boundingBox = boxObservation?.boundingBox ?? .zero
        str = candidate.string
        self.arrayString.append(str!)
        let rectInImg = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(boundingBox, Int((imageView.frame.size.width)), Int((imageView.frame.size.height)))
        let convertedRect = self.getConvertedRect(boundingBox: observation.boundingBox, inImage:image!.size , containedIn: (imageView.bounds.size))
        drawBoundBox(rect: convertedRect)
        return rectInImg
    }
    print(arrayString)
    print(boundingRect)
    
}
func drawBoundBox(rect: CGRect) {
    uiButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    uiButton?.frame = rect
    uiButton?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemPink.cgColor
    uiButton?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    uiButton?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    uiButton?.tag = arrayString.count
    imageView.addSubview(uiButton ?? UIButton())
    uiButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func pressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
    alert(key: arrayString[sender.tag - 1])
    
}

//MARK: CONVERT THE NORMALISED BOUNDING RECT

func getConvertedRect(boundingBox: CGRect, inImage imageSize: CGSize, containedIn containerSize: CGSize) -> CGRect {
    
    let rectOfImage: CGRect
    
    let imageAspect = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
    let containerAspect = containerSize.width / containerSize.height
    
    if imageAspect > containerAspect { /// image extends left and right
        let newImageWidth = containerSize.height * imageAspect /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newX = -(newImageWidth - containerSize.width) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: newX, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: containerSize.height)
        
    } else { /// image extends top and bottom
        let newImageHeight = containerSize.width * (1 / imageAspect) /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newY = -(newImageHeight - containerSize.height) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: newY, width: containerSize.width, height: newImageHeight)
    }
    
    let newOriginBoundingBox = CGRect(
        x: boundingBox.origin.x,
        y: 1 - boundingBox.origin.y - boundingBox.height,
        width: boundingBox.width,
        height: boundingBox.height
    )
    
    var convertedRect = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(newOriginBoundingBox, Int(rectOfImage.width), Int(rectOfImage.height))
    
    /// add the margins
    convertedRect.origin.x += rectOfImage.origin.x
    convertedRect.origin.y += rectOfImage.origin.y
    
    return convertedRect
    
}

//MARK: RESIZE THE IMAGE ACCORD TO DEVICE
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size
    
    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height
    
    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }
    
    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
    
    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return newImage!
}

//MARK: POPPING ALERT WITH STRING
func alert(key:String){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "String", message: key, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
       
    }
    let copyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default) {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        UIPasteboard.general.string = key
       
    }
    alertController.addAction(copyAction)
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: We get normalise bounding box points , first we need to convert that into real for that #getConvertedRect func is used , we also need to fit the image according to Screen so for that #resizeImage func is used.